# How can I sample equally from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have some observations, each with an indicated class from `1` to `n`.  Each of these classes may not necessarily occur equally in the data set.

How can I equally sample from the dataframe?  Right now I do something like...

```
frames = []
classes = df.classes.unique()

for i in classes:
    g = df[df.classes = i].sample(sample_size)
    frames.append(g)

equally_sampled = pd.concat(frames)
```

Is there a pandas function to equally sample?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html  ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For more elegance you can do this:

```
df.groupby('classes').apply(lambda x: x.sample(sample_size))
```

---

#### Extension:

You can make the `sample_size` a function of group size to sample with equal probabilities (or proportionately):

```
nrows = len(df)
total_sample_size = 1e4
df.groupby('classes').\
    apply(lambda x: x.sample(int((x.count()/nrows)*total_sample_size)))
```

It won't result in the exact number of rows as `total_sample_size` but sampling will be more proportional than the naive method.

Comment: You should use `group_keys=False` in the groupby method to avoid the index getting replaced with the redundant group names.

Answer (score 4):

While the accepted answer is awesome, another approach when the dataset is highly imbalanced:

For example: A dataset has **100K data-points** (or rows) out of which **16K data-points are label `0`** (-ve class) and remaining **84K data-points are label `1`** (+ve class). To extract a **sample of size 50K data-points** with all 16K -ve class and filling the remaining space with +ve class, we can do below steps:

```py
from sklearn import utils

# Pick all -ve class, fill the sample with +ve class and shuffle.
df = utils.shuffle(df.groupby("class_label").head(50000 - 16000))

# Reset index by dropping old index if not required.
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) # Optional step.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Sampling with permutations: in this instance we are sampling 1/3 of the
> data 19 times and stacking stacking it back each time

```
df1 = df.take(np.random.permutation(int(df.shape[0]))[:int(int(df.shape[0])/3)])

for i in range(19):
    x = df.take(np.random.permutation(int(df.shape[0]))[:int(int(df.shape[0])/3)])
    df1 = pd.concat([df1,x], axis=0)
```